# Import data in R from a text file containing multi header rows and whitespaces

Tags: r, dataframe, import, readr

I want to upload a data file that contains multiple header rows and whitespaces into R. I have copied the data here

```
# File name
#
#@   1  "Some text"                                                   "aa"
#@   2  "Some text"                                                   "bb"
#@   3  "Some text"                                                   "cc"
#@   4  "Some text"                                                   "dd"
#@   5  "Some text"                                                   "ee"
#@   6  "Some text"                                                   "ff"

#
#
#
#

 0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  
 1.000000e-03  3.727051e-04  2.532203e-04  4.736003e-04  3.727051e-07  0.000000e+00   
 2.000000e-03  2.266785e-03  1.540081e-03  2.880429e-03  2.639490e-06  0.000000e+00  
 3.000000e-03  7.538553e-03  5.121786e-03  9.579321e-03  1.017804e-05  0.000000e+00   
 4.000000e-03  1.838835e-02  1.249329e-02  2.336627e-02  2.856639e-05  0.000000e+00  
 5.000000e-03  3.703296e-02  2.516073e-02  4.705817e-02  6.559935e-05  0.000000e+00 
 6.000000e-03  2.266785e-03  1.540081e-03  2.880429e-03  2.639490e-06  0.000000e+00  
 7.000000e-03  7.538553e-03  5.121786e-03  9.579321e-03  1.017804e-05  0.000000e+00   
 8.000000e-03  1.838835e-02  1.249329e-02  2.336627e-02  2.856639e-05  0.000000e+00  
 9.000000e-03  3.703296e-02  2.516073e-02  4.705817e-02  6.559935e-05  0.000000e+00
```

As you can see, it contains 9 rows and 6 columns. The issue is there is bunch of header data on top of the actual data set that contains the column names. I tried using the read_table command and whitespace delimiter, but the columns were limited to 3, instead of 6

```
dat <- read_table("example.txt", col_names = F)
```

I would like to import the data, convert to numeric and label each column with the header names listed in the file. So name of the first column would be "Some text aa", 2nd column would be "Some text bb" and so on. Is there a way to get this? I have 100 such files and would like to automate the process

Comment: You may use the `skip` argument to skip the first couple of rows of header and then modify the column names later

Comment: @akrun Oh, I dont know why it keep getting deleted. Is there another way to upload it? I tried skip, but the number of columns is still 3 instead of 6

Comment: If your file is not too big, just put the raw file contents (or the first 10 lines or so) into a code block. It seems that the use of `file.io` is not working well for you, and the use of external links for sample data is often discouraged on SO for just this reason: nobody can see your data, so this is not reproducible. (It shows "Deleted", btw.)

Comment: @r2evans I have coiped and pasted the data here

Comment: As already suggested, `read_table(filename, skip = 13, col_names = FALSE)` worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file is `quux.txt`, then

```r
dat <- read.table("quux.txt", skip = 13, header = FALSE)
dat
#      V1           V2           V3           V4           V5 V6
# 1 0.000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.000000e+00  0
# 2 0.001 0.0003727051 0.0002532203 0.0004736003 3.727051e-07  0
# 3 0.002 0.0022667850 0.0015400810 0.0028804290 2.639490e-06  0
# 4 0.003 0.0075385530 0.0051217860 0.0095793210 1.017804e-05  0
# 5 0.004 0.0183883500 0.0124932900 0.0233662700 2.856639e-05  0
# 6 0.005 0.0370329600 0.0251607300 0.0470581700 6.559935e-05  0
```

From here, you can extract the column names with

```r
nms <- readLines(pipe("grep '^#@' quux.txt")) |>
  sub(pattern = '.*"(\\S+)"\\s*$', replacement = '\\1')
nms
# [1] "aa" "bb" "cc" "dd" "ee" "ff"
names(dat) <- nms
dat
#      aa           bb           cc           dd           ee ff
# 1 0.000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.000000e+00  0
# 2 0.001 0.0003727051 0.0002532203 0.0004736003 3.727051e-07  0
# 3 0.002 0.0022667850 0.0015400810 0.0028804290 2.639490e-06  0
# 4 0.003 0.0075385530 0.0051217860 0.0095793210 1.017804e-05  0
# 5 0.004 0.0183883500 0.0124932900 0.0233662700 2.856639e-05  0
# 6 0.005 0.0370329600 0.0251607300 0.0470581700 6.559935e-05  0
```

Comment: Oh thanks a lot. If I also want to add the "Some text "  to "aa" and make it one string "Some text aa" should I change the pattern or replacement?

Comment: Yeah, you'd work with the `sub(...)` to get it. If you look at the return from `readLines` (before `sub`), something like `readLines(pipe("grep '#@' quux.txt")) |> sub(pattern='[^"]*"(.*)"\\s*$', replacement='\\1') |> gsub(pattern='[" ]+', replacement=' ')`

Comment: Thanks. Instead of quux.txt after "grep '#@', I would like to insert a path to the file. So I was trying to store the path using:
path <- here::here("data", "quux.txt")

How do I insert this path inside pipe?

Comment: Probably something like `pipe(paste("grep '^#@'", here::here("data", "quux.txt")))` (assuming no spaces in the path).

Comment: oh Unfortunately, I have a space in path  - which I cannot rename . Its onedrive folder name. Is there a way around?

Comment: wrap in `sQuote`?

Comment: I got it using the following code: I am trying to choose the first file in the folder and read the header lines
 foo      <- here::here("folder1", "folder2")
first_file <- here::here("folder1", "folder2", list.files(foo)[1])

  nms <- readLines(pipe(paste("grep", "'^#@'", paste0("'", first_file, "'")))) |>
  sub(pattern='[^"]*"(.*)"\\s*$', replacement='\\1') |> gsub(pattern='[" ]+', replacement=' ')

The issue is it works on mac - but fails on windows. Any way it can be resolved?

Comment: Does the pipe() behave differently in mac and windows?

Comment: I have tested this on windows and linux, it worked both; I don't have mac available; if you're on a Mac, @ACE, have you tested this and does my answer not behave the same for you as it does here?

Comment: I tested on mac, it works. I have shown one of the header lines from the raw data below:
`[3] "#@   1  \"Time\"       \"s\""`        

I want to extract "Time" and "s" from the header lines. As you suggested in the comment, I tried the following

`foo <- here::here("folder1", "folder2") `

`first_file <- here::here("folder1", "folder2", list.files(foo)[1])`

`nms <- readLines(pipe(paste("grep", "'^#@'", paste0("'", first_file, "'")))) |> sub(pattern='[^"]*"(.*)"\\s*$', replacement='\\1') |> gsub(pattern='[" ]+', replacement=' ')`

Output in windows is character(0)

Comment: Unfortunately I can't trouble that error since I don't see it. Does `readLines(pipe(...))` return empty without the following `sub(..)`?

Comment: Yes, readLines(pipe(...)) returns character(0)

 pipe(paste("grep", "'^#@'", paste0("'", p_header, "'"))) returns:
A connection with                                                                                                                                                                         description "C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe /c grep '^#@' 'C:/Users/ee/OneDrive - xxx/Training/xxx/R_data_analysis/xxx/xxx/xxx.txt'"
class     "pipe"
mode      "r"
text      "text"
opened      "closed"
can read    "yes"                                                     
can write   "yes"

Comment: Okay, so either that grep is not posix and we need to add `-E`, or something about the path is a problem. Try `grep -E ...` instead, and if that returns nothing, try `pipe(paste("cat", "^#@", sQuote(p_header,FALSE)))`, and if that doesn't work try `dQuote` instead of `sQuote`.

Comment: r2evans : I tried all three, it still doesn't work,wonder what the problem is. Should grep -E... come under paste ("grep", "-E", .. ?

I can post it as another question as well, if it is easier

Comment: yes, `paste("grep", "-E", "'^#@'", ...)`, I suspect that it has something to do with working within the OneDrive structure. Just for grins, try copying that `.txt` file into a different (non-OneDrive) directory, and for more grins, make sure the whole path has no embedded spaces. It's not always a problem, but occasionally both conditions can be problematic.

Comment: I tried, again same error. I ensured there were no spaces as well

Comment: This is truly perplexing. I don't know how comfortable you are with shell prompts, but fi you can go to bash (perhaps git-bash if you have git-for-windows installed) or go to windows' `cmd.exe` prompt in the directory with your text file. If `grep` is not found, you may need a full-path such as `c:/rtools42/usr/bin/grep.exe` (or `40`); in the shell prompt type in `grep -E '^#@' xxx.txt` and see if it returns anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251131/discussion-between-ace-and-r2evans).